# wordpress search: create field(s) to exclude word or phrase from search results

Tags: wordpress, search, phrase

For instance if I built a job board with wordpress and I'm searching for "marketing" but I want to remove all results with the phrase "commission only"

Answer (score 0):

Write your own query for the search function. You can use the LIKE condition in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tag = 'marketing' and category not like 'commission only'
```

Comment: can you give me the php full code to block posts containing these words with "commission only", "equity" and "local" from the search results